# Comparing Environments

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am a SQL Server dba. I have been asked to compare our production environment to test from a number of different perspectives. These are windows patch level,sql service pack, to database size and compabilty modes. I also need to identify global environmental differences such as max dop settings to memory allocation. Can anyone advise of useful tsql or powershell where this can be captured as a report style format.

Comment: Removed now from link above

Comment: That would basically be a custom script, and could be relatively robust.  What have you tried?

Comment: Thanks. I have an idea. For example sp_configure will give me the instance info. I just need some scipt examples.

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is to use :

Discover, Diagnose, and Document ALL Your SQL Servers On Your Coffee Break using [**SQL Power Doc**](https://sqlpowerdoc.codeplex.com/) written by  kendal vandyke

This is written in Powershell.